# JAVA, SQL, insert into no-duplicates

Tags: java, sql, derby, insert-into, no-duplicates

I am trying to insert into a table without duplicates. I am using SQL `derbyclient` in Java. The code is not working (error with `'where not exists'`). Any idea?

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PetroleumDataStorageSystemDB;create=true");
PreparedStatement statement;
int i = 1;
int progress = 0;
for (Refuel refuelList1 : refuelList) {
     progress = (i / refuelList.size()) * 100;
     String sql = "INSERT INTO refuel (id_tank, time, fuel_volume, "
                  + "refueling_speed) VALUES (?,?,?,?) "
                  + "WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM refuel WHERE "
                  + "id_tank = ? AND time = ? AND fuel_volume = ? AND "
                  + "refueling_speed = ?)";
     statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
     statement.setInt(1, refuelList1.getTankID());
     statement.setString(2, refuelList1.getTime());
     statement.setDouble(3, refuelList1.getFuelVolume());
     statement.setDouble(4, refuelList1.getRefuelingSpeed());
     statement.execute();
     i++;
}
```

Comment: I presume the ID is unique? if that's the case then remove it from your where not exists as it would be different?

Comment: Glassfish. The table do not have a primary key.

Comment: Insert + where is not correct. Use Insert + select instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you build your query. That isnt a valid `INSERT` syntaxis

Try something like this on your db first **with dummy values**.

```
INSERT INTO refuel (id_tank, time, fuel_volume, refueling_speed) 
 SELECT ?, ?, ?, ? 
 FROM refuel
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                   FROM refuel 
                   WHERE
                       id_tank = ? 
                   AND time = ? 
                   AND fuel_volume = ?
                   AND refueling_speed = ?);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 8 question mark in your statement.

You have to set all of them!

After that you can check again and see if there are other errors.

Comment: If you find the answer is correct and useful you can upvote it and flag it as correct answer with the green flag. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a `WHERE` clause after a `VALUES` list.

Have a look [here](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj40774.html) for valid Derby `INSERT` statement syntax.

Try something like this instead (notice the use of `sysibm.sysdummy1`, which guarantees that you only ever insert a single record at most.  If you put an actual table name in there, you may potentially insert multiple records a time. Careful with that.):

```sql
INSERT INTO refuel (id_tank, tank, fuel_volume, refueling_speed)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
  FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM refuel
                    WHERE id_tank = ?
                      AND time = ?
                      AND fuel_volume = ?
                      AND refueling_speed = ?)
```

Also, as noted by `Davide Lorenzo MARINO`, make sure you set all the binding parameters correctly.